# rank of certain block matrix need to clarified

Tags: matrix-rank

Given that $E$ is an $n_1\times n_1$ matrix  and $C$ is a $p_1\times n_1$ matrix. We are given that  rank of $\begin{bmatrix}I_{n_1}-E\\C\end{bmatrix}=rank(C)$ then we need to show

rank of $\begin{bmatrix}E\\C\end{bmatrix}=n_1$

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank hypothesis amounts to saying that
$$CX = 0\quad \Longrightarrow\quad E X = X$$
For any $X\in {\mathbb K}^{n_1}$, suppose that
$$\binom{E}{C}X = 0$$
it follows that $CX = 0$ and $E X = 0$, but then $X = EX=0$. The nullspace
of $\binom{E}{C}$ being $\{0\}$, it follows that its rank is $n_1$.